# Prevent downloading pictures like Instagram

Tags: javascript, instagram

How does Instragram prevent downloading pictures? http://instagram.com/p/elPBOqFWVl/embed/#

I know the link to the image is http://distilleryimage5.ak.instagram.com/f883e09023e111e3a35d22000aaa05f7_7.jpg which can be found in the code but how is it not selectable and no context menu for downloading pops up when you right click it. Most sites use a transparent picture over the actual picture but there's some fancy javascript going on by the looks of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use firebug to debug that page, you'll find that it's not actually an image. Rather, it's a div with the background-image property set to the link to the image. Once you actually click on the link to the img that's specified in the CSS, you can easily download it.

Upon inspection, the css for the div is

```
element.style {
    background-image: url(http://distilleryimage5.ak.instagram.com/f883e09023e111e3a35d22000aaa05f7_7.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was an image because you could click and drag it on Firefox. I guess that works for DIVs too?

Comment: Yes, with HTML5, almost any elements can be dragged and dropped. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped at all, then please accept and/or up vote it! Thanks!

Comment: Seems that now the images on instagram online are displayed using <img/> but are still not downloadable

Comment: I'm afraid it's no longer the case. Any idea how they do it now?

Comment: I've spent a while trying to understand how Instagram does it now, and it is mysterious. It involves the new "srcset" attribute on an <img> but beyond that I would really like to know how they do it.